# what's the difference between CPU time sum and CPU time avg azure

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

What's the difference between CPU time sum and CPU time avg?
Why is the CPU time avg larger than CPU time?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its seems you are trying to know about [azure CPU calculation metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#understand-metrics). Please have a look.

**CPU Time:** The amount of CPU consumed by each app in seconds,  because one of their quotas is defined in CPU minutes used by the app. Its calculated over one application uses.

**CPU percentage**: CPU percentage is a good indication of the overall usage across all instances. Let's say, you have 5 application these metrics calculated all of your application uses in average.

**Why CPU time avg is large than CPU time?**

I think in your screen shot given metrics is alright where your total CPU time is `18.05` that mean all if your apps consume this amount and each application consume on average `2.10`

See the screen shot

[image]

For details you could take a look [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#cpu-time-vs-cpu-percentage)

Comment: How about the vertical ordinate? Why sum is much lower?

Comment: Because in that specific duration consumption was lowest of your all application. You see the time, usually that's supposed to called as application idle time when consumption seems low.Sorry for the late reply. never mind.  Let me know if you have any more question.

Comment: Do you mean when consumption is high, the vertical ordinate is idle time?
when consumption is high, the vertical ordinate is the amount of CPU consumed by each app in seconds?

Comment: No I didn't mean that, just opposite. when consumption become higher CPU uses will be higher. Yeah CPU consumption calculated in second  [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#understand-metrics) Let men know if you have any more concern :)

Comment: Sorry for my silly questions.
When I select CPU TIME AVG, the vertical ordinate is the amount of CPU consumed by each app in seconds.
When I select CPU TIME SUM, the vertical ordinate is idle time.
Right??

Comment: For example, at 6:00 am, CPU TIME AVG is around 2 minutes, but CPU TIME SUM is around 12 seconds according to my picture. How to understand it?

Comment: @Jeff_hu idle consumption doesn't mean no consumption, may be lower than pick hours. Sorry for the wrong spelling!

Comment: CPU TIME SUM is showing idle consumption. Got it! Thank you

Comment: @Jeff_hu See the latest updated screen shot. Hope everything will be clear now. You are welcome.